# fatal error LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/OUT:' in VC++ Kernel

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker, operating-system

I am making a kernel in Visual C++ according to to the tutorial [here](http://ksrenevasan.blogspot.com/). However, when I try to build it I receive the error `LINK : fatal error LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/OUT:'`. I would provide source code, but it is unnecessary because I haven't changed it from the tutorial. However, for quick reference, here are my C/C++ options:

```
/Gd /Fm /TC /c kernel.c
```

And here is my Link options:

```
/safeseh:no /filealign:0x1000 /BASE:0x100000 /ENTRY:__multiboot_entry__ /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OUT: kernel.exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No space after the colon:

```
/OUT:kernel.exe
```